# How to center this layout? - Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to center a layout, but i can't ;x It's aligned to the Left.

Here is a code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shaper"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_featured"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="12sp"

            android:text=""
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_offer_badge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcardname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtcardcredits"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/md_brown_800"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcardcredits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="200 Credits"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
            android:textSize="@dimen/listgroupitemcredittextsize"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fraginvite_btnheight"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fraginvite_btnheight"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/greyLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@color/md_brown_800" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I added a code of the XML layout file below!

Please help guys! Tried solutions on stack but couldn't fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try android:gravity="center"

Comment: Or you can have a one more relative layout as a parent to this linear layout that will work with this same linearlayout code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into FrameLayout and set child layout gravity to center_horizontal

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout   //your layout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your xml it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/shaper"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_featured"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_offer_badge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcardname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtcardcredits"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_800"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcardcredits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="200 Credits"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
        android:textSize="@dimen/listgroupitemcredittextsize"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fraginvite_btnheight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fraginvite_btnheight"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_offer_badge"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<View
    android:id="@+id/greyLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@color/md_brown_800" />
```

Comment: try it and let me know